# Fan and nonFan pages for my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want my application to have two spare screens, one for the non Fan user (the ones that didn't press the button like) and one for the fans. How can I do that without asking the users to authorize my app? Do I have to use pages or page tabs first? or something else?

I tried with JS SDK and $_REQUEST["signed_request"] but there is no info if the user "likes" the app. I also tried FQL methods, but the most tables ask for the user_likes permission.

I'm totally lost with that and any help would be gratefull.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this from the **signed_request** parameter, which is added to the request URL for your app on the page tab or canvas URL you provided. The signed_request param contains JSON data which includes the id of the page your app is installed on, and an additional **liked** field if the user has already liked the page. You can use this field to redirect users to the appropriate view for your app.

See the section labelled "Integrating with Facebook APIs" at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ for more info.

Comment: does it need specific options selected in the app creation migration preferences? I have the following  set:

Stream post URL security: Disabled
Remove offline_access permission: Enabled
Timezone-less events: Enabled
Forces use of login secret for auth.login: Disabled
Enhanced Auth Dialog: Enabled
Page Hours Format: Enabled
Batch API Exceptions Format: Enabled
July 2012 Breaking Changes: Disabled
Include Checkins with Statuses: Enabled

Comment: No, this should work for all canvas and page tab apps in the same way, as long as your canvas URL or page tab URL is set. For canvas apps, you won't get the page ID in the JSON, but you should still get the 'liked' field.

Comment: ok. and if you want to check the main page of a company? In case that I want to check the page with id 1234567890 and if the user is not fan of the page, then the app should lead him in a page to ask him to become one!!! How this can be done without asking to authorize the app first?

Comment: That can't be done. It's different to what you asked initially. The signed_request will give you liked information about the current user on the current page tab app only.

Comment: There got to be a way. I mean, I know that Shortstack (http://www.shortstack.com) does such a thing, but I don't know how they manage to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: If you get the user to authorise your app and give you permission to see their likes you can check if they like any page, but you'll need users to accept those permissions

Comment: You are totally right Igy. Unfortunatelly, my conclusion is that you can't do that without user's permission. Maybe you could with FBML or something that facebook changed.